# Simulating a simple memory leak in Visual Studio with a bit confusing result

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, dump, delete-operator

Here is one very simple question(or at least at first sight).Let's say we have the following procedure:

```
void procedure(void)
{
          int x = new int;
          x=42;
}
```

When I call to this procedure in my program it should lead to the so called memory leak, right?I've been encountering such bugs while working on a small project and then compiler was outputting something like : detected memory leak.Dumping memory block ...Now I try to simulate a memory leak and see what compiler outputs but it doesn't complain at all(I use Visual Studio).
Is there really a memory leak that's my question .

Comment: Does your compiler accept/compile that? If it does, time to upgrade - it's not valid C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is memory leak. You use C++ and calling new operator will reserve 4 bytes of memory on the heap. - delete is not called.
If you will cal this function 2 million times, about 8 MB of memory will leak.

In this short program part - it allocates memory and pointer is converted to int (hidden conversion). Some compilers may not detect tis situation, another may.

Comment: It's won't reserve 4 bytes. It reserves an unspecified amount of bytes.

Comment: @PaulManta: it would reserve *at least* `sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: @AndréCaron Which is an amount not specified by the standard.

Comment: Yes, new int reserves some memory: 2 bytes, 4 bytes, 8 bytes - depending on compiler used, operating system, etc. But this is memory leak.

Comment: @PaulManta: Sorry for being pedantic, but while the actual number of bytes is implementation defined, it *is* specified: "at least `sizeof(int)` bytes".  Unspecified means *any* number of bytes can be returned.

Comment: @AndréCaron Unspecified means just that, unspecified. Not that any number of bytes can be returned. You can impose some restrictions, but unless you specify it fully, it's still unspecified.

Comment: @PaulManta: in the C++ standard, *unspecified* and *implementation defined* have different meanings.  The former refers to a no-man's land while the second implies that the implementation may choose a suitable value provided that it is documented.  This may not correspond to the way you normally use these words, but when discussing C++, you should stick to the same usage as the standard.

Comment: @AndréCaron Are yiu sure the first of those words isn't "undefined"?

Comment: It's certainly not "undefined". That's reserved for a class of really bad things. In this case, it's _both_ implementation-defined _and_ unspecified how many bytes are returned. The part that's implementation-defined is `sizeof(int)`; the part that's not is how many more bytes are returned (`new` may return more bytes than requested, and an implementation need not document this).

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to call this, because it won't compile. Presumably you really meant something like:

```
void procedure(void) { 
    int *x = new int;
    *x = 42;
}
```

Yes, this has a memory leak which I'd expect VC++ to complain about (when compiled in debug mode). In release mode, it won't normally check for leaks anyway, but even if it did, it wouldn't surprise me if the compiler detected that none of this had any real effect, so invoking it was optimized out completely (thus eliminating the memory leak). I'm not at all sure that would happen, but it wouldn't be a huge surprise if it did either.

Comment: Thank you.That's exactly what I meant to do and actually I did it and VisualStudio didn't complain in debug mode about any memory leak but that's not so important because I wanted to know if I really caused a memory leak.Thank you very much for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong <sub><sup>**Edit** me too :) I need to learn to read first</sup></sub>

you probably wanted:

```
void procedure(void)
{
          int* px = new int;
          *px = 42;
}
```

Which assigns the *value* 42 to the `integer` *pointed to* by `x`

And **yes** that really is a (small) memory leak. If the function gets called many times, you'll have a bigger memory leak :)

Comment: @Max & @Mat: i've _`fixed`_ my f**ck since then, I guess. Ninja edit just a little to quick this time

Comment: @JerryCoffin: now, coincidence would be that in vim (my editor), `xp` will reverse two characters. I hope I get _those_ right or it will start looking very strange :) Thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.I was a bit confused considering the output because I didn't get any notifications about any memory leaks.